# node js store returned API key as variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, servlets

I am new to node and am trying to using [A node.js library for the Pardot API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pardot)

This I pass my `userKey`, `email` and `password` to pardot, this returns my `api_key`.

I am using the following code to authenticate, then when I run my node server I can see the api_key being passed back.

how do I then store that api_key as a variable to then use to post data to the API?

**my node code**

```
var nodePardot = require('node-pardot');

// Create client using email, password and user_key
nodePardot.PardotAPI({
    userKey: 'kyujk',
    email: 'uu.uuy@uu.co.uk',
    password: 'uit.09',
    DEBUG: true
}, function(err, client) {
    // Authentication completed
    console.log('Authentication completed');

    // gets api key
    var api_key = api_key;
    console.log('key',api_key);
});
```

**my console output**

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Server started! At http://localhost:8080
Initializing node-pardot in DEBUG mode
params {"email":"bhyuyten.jj@jyj.co.uk","password":"tyjt.09","user_key":"yjty76","format":"json"}
uri https://pi.pardot.com/api/login/version/3?email=ss.jyj%s.co.uk&password=tyjt.09&user_key=yjty76&api_key=&format=json
parsedResponse {"@attributes":{"stat":"ok","version":1},"api_key":"878074492492dhjjk67u","version":4}
Authentication completed
key undefined
parsedResponse {"@attributes":{"stat":"ok","version":1},"api_key":"878074492492dhjjk67u","version":4}


var nodePardot = require('node-pardot');

    // Create client using email, password and user_key
    nodePardot.PardotAPI({
        userKey: 'fdgr',
        email: 'rg.gg@gg.co.uk',
        password: 'dfherg',
        DEBUG: true
    }, function(err, client) {
        // Authentication completed
        console.log('Authentication completed');

        // gets api key
        var api_key = api_key;
        console.log('key',api_key);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source of node-pardot [here](https://github.com/Datahero/node-pardot/blob/development/lib/pardot/PardotAPI_v3.js#L23) and [here](https://github.com/Datahero/node-pardot/blob/development/lib/pardot/PardotAPI_v3.js#L50), it looks like the API Key is at `client.apiKey`

Also, you should always check for the error condition in nodejs-style callback functions!

```
nodePardot.PardotAPI({
    userKey: '...',
    email: '...',
    password: '...',
    DEBUG: true
}, function(err, client) {
    if(err){
        // Authentication failed
        // handle error
        console.error("Authentication Failed", err)
    } else {
        // Authentication successful
        // gets api key
        var api_key = client.apiKey;
        console.log("Authentication successful", api_key);
    }
});
```

P.S. You should never post API keys and credentials on public forums and QA sites

Comment: Hi @riyax dont worry all the API and info I posted was fake, but thanks for the heads up. great answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to assign the value of an undeclared variable to itself in

```
var api_key = api_key;
```

You should be assigning it the value in the response, i.e.

```
var api_key = client.api_key;
```

Comment: hmm, looks good but im still getting key undefined in my console

Comment: what do you get when you log `client`?